# Pandas - "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I have two Dataframes :

```
db = pd.read_csv('partena_codes.csv', dtype={'code': str})

    code     label
0  00200      Work
1  00600  Holidays
2  01000   Illness
3  15500   Absence
```

and

```
with open('selections.json') as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.DataFrame(data['selections'])

df => 

description    label  position_id                  startDate  \
Blablblablabl  Absence          1.0  2017-07-19T19:20:30+01:00   

                stopDate  person_id  
2017-07-19T20:20:30+01:00     768930
```

What i'm trying to do is:

```
select_code = db[(db['label'] == df['label'])]
```

But i'm stuck with that Error :

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @piotr-kaczyński mentioned, this error arises when your DataFrames have different indexes and/or different shapes. I think this *might* be what you want:

```
select_code = db.merge(df, left_on='label', right_on='label')
```

[Link to documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge).

Comment: Thank you ! that's exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

These two dataframes have different indexes - if you select one "column" it becomes a Series with an index of the dataframe (these are the labels the error is about). The second one has some strange index.

And what is it you are trying to accomplish? If you try to compare series, they have to be either the same length or use some kind of operator like `any` or `all`

Comment: What i'm trying to do is to use my csv file as a database table: "for X label give me the code corresponding". But i can't compare db['label']  and df['label'] ...